# How do I get jconsole working quickly over X11

Tags: x11, jconsole

Scenario:
I am trying to get some realtime analysis across our threads to isolate the cause of a thread  deadlock.

I have an issue where jconsole was very slow when running via SSH with X11 forwarding.

I was inexperience up to 30 seconds delay per click.

What can be done to make JConsole run at a reasonable speed.

Comment: Answering my own question.

Answer (score 4):

Launch jconsole in the following way

```
jconsole -J-Dsun.java2d.xrender=True
```

jconsole is faster but is still very slow to respond.

The next step is to *Minimize any graphs*.

The table containing threads can now be browsed quickly.

Comment: Running JDK8; I have no problem with graphs. The option alone: -J-Dsun.java2d.xrender=True make jconsole respond almost instantly on every panel. Without this option, the round-trip delay is like 20 sec per click!